# Add command arguments using inline if-statement in bash

Tags: bash

I'd like to add an argument to a command in bash only if a variable evaluates to a certain value. For example this works:

```
test=1
if [ "${test}" == 1 ]; then
    ls -la -R
else
    ls -R   
fi
```

The problem with this approach is that I have to duplicate `ls -R` both when `test` is `1` or if it's something else. I'd prefer if I could write this in one line instead such as this (pseudo code that doesn't work):

```
ls (if ${test} == 1 then -la) -R
```

I've tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
test=1
ls `if [ $test -eq 1 ]; then -la; fi` -R
```

This gives me the following error:

```
./test.sh: line 3: -la: command not found
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

A more idiomatic version of [svlasov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28678587/45375):

```
ls $( (( test == 1 )) && printf %s '-la' ) -R
```

<sup>Since `echo` understands a few options itself, it's safer to use `printf %s` to make sure that the text to print is not mistaken for an option.

Note that the command substitution *must not* be quoted here - which is fine in the case at hand, but calls for a more robust approach in general - see below.</sup>

However, in general, the more **robust approach is to build up arguments in an *array*** and pass it as a whole:

```
# Build up array of arguments...
args=()
(( test == 1 )) && args+=( '-la' )
args+=( '-R' )

# ... and pass it to `ls`.
ls "${args[@]}"
```

**Update**: The OP asks how to conditionally add an additional, variable-based argument to yield `ls -R -la "$PWD"`.
In that case, the array approach is a must: each argument must become its own array element, which is crucial for supporting arguments that may have embedded whitespace:

```
(( test == 1 )) && args+= ( '-la' "$PWD" ) # Add each argument as its own array element.
```

---

As for why your command,

```
 ls `if [ $test -eq 1 ]; then -la; fi` -R
```

didn't work:

A command between backticks (or its modern, nestable equivalent, `$(...)`) - a so-called [command substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution) - is executed just like any other shell command (albeit in a *sub*-shell) and the whole construct is replaced with the command's *stdout* output.

Thus, your command tries to *execute* the string `-la`, which fails. To send it to *stdout*, as is needed here, you must use a command such as `echo` or `printf`.

Comment: Using `[[ "$ENV_VARIABLE" == "true" ]] && args+=('-la')` you are able to use environment variables checking thier value conditionally.

Answer (score 9):

Print the argument with `echo`:

```
test=1
ls `if [ $test -eq 1 ]; then echo "-la"; fi` -R
```

Answer (score 5):

I can't say how acceptable this is, but:

```
test=1
ls ${test:+'-la'} -R
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/16753536/1 for a conditional truth table.

Comment: This and the array-based answer are the only two that aren't awful.

Answer (score 4):

Another answer without using `eval` and using BASH arrays:

```
myls() { local arr=(ls); [[ $1 -eq 1 ]] && arr+=(-la); arr+=(-R); "${arr[@]}"; }
```

Use it as:

```
myls
myls "$test"
```

This script builds whole command in an array `arr` and preserves the original order of command options.